# BizTalk MAP project REBUILD takes very long time

Tags: schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

My BizTalk Project Rebuild takes very very long time especially for MAP Projects, this is relatively very small schema and before it was taking very less time but suddenly the REBUILD time is up to 30-40 mins.

Please provide your expect comment on and if you known any cause for this.

Regards

Comment: Even a blank MAP with no mapping take 2 -3 mins to build, before it was in seconds.

Comment: So what changed just before the the time increased?  I have had problems with certain schemas which had a record that had a type that included a sub record of the same type (e.g. nested structure that could repeat) combined in combination with a default value for some fields.

Comment: @SAM, did you find out why map project took so long? Have the same problem...added a few maps with two messages as source, now it takes like 5-10 minutes to build project.

Comment: i have similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that with BTS 2016 / VS2015 the maps build very slowly. I can't explain why but running the build from a visual studio command prompt results in much faster builds. It's a bit of a pain because need to remember to close VS first.

Navigate to the solution folder and run "msbuild .sln"

Answer (score 0):

Used Rob Bowman's answer as principle, but I manage to just unload projects from solution from Solution Explorer directly (mark all projects, right click, and select Unload Project), and then run the

`msbuild *.sln /t:Clean,Rebuild`

from Visual Studio Command Prompt. When finished, just reload projects in Solution Explorer.

It saves me minutes (!) when I need to rebuild solution.